# making UI layout with custom shape buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to make a layout like this. This app will be for my own use only i don't have much experience in graphics with android. I have draw these images and saved as PNG separately. I tried to put them in a layout, but i face to many difficulties with spacing and correct placing. But PNG is a rectangle and it clicks outside the image. So i think about preparing all possible situation and load all image as background. Touchable area rectangle(invisible) would be drawn inside button.

- Is it a good practice to load image as a background when touch? I would have 16x4=64 backgrounds
- What difficulties i can face in the future?
- Should i stick to the black background and load separate buttons?
- If above "Yes", then to draw background and image is better to resize image in pixels in a drawing SW like Corel? In my case 1280x720

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCpa5.png):[image: my image]

And the touch area would be something like this so i don't think it is possible to misclick it?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U46a0.png):[image: touch area]

Comment: Keep in mind that your Buttons will always be **rectangles**. You can still draw this custom UI, with some little tricks.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What kind of little tricks are you talking about?

Comment: Trick: the images are splitted across consequent buttons (i.e.: some parts of the image which ideally belong to one button are shared with that one which is on top and/or on bottom)

Answer (score 0):

With classic [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), you won't be able to do non-rectangular view (you can draw want ever you want but your touch area is still rectangular).

The easiest way is to handle the [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) on a large View (fillin the screen with your image as background) with a [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and calculate above which (fake) button you are.

For highlights you can use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) (could be the tricks @Frank.N.Stein talks about).

The hardest way is to use OpenGL graphics ... good luck for a someone who doesn't "have much experience [...]".